# Can I use regexp to get text inside quotes?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like:

```
some text here 'quoted text here' some more text
```

I'd like to get the 'quoted text here' without the quotes. Besides using indexOf(') and then substring, how can I look this up using a regular expression in Java?

Comment: Use this regex `'([^']*)'` and use first captured group

Comment: Split it on the single quotes, and get element 1 (and other odd-numbered elements, if appropriate) from the resulting array.

Comment: Use **capturing groups**. For example with a pattern like `'(.+)'` and then start matching this with `Matcher#find` and extract the group with `Matcher#group`, the group is **group 1**. You may need to escape `'` as `\\'`, I'm not sure, just test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String text = "some text here 'quoted text here' some more text";
String regex = "'(.*?)'";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
if (m.find()){
        String s = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: `'` is not special in regex (at least in Java flavor) so there is no need to escape it.

Comment: Right, I fixed the typo